# logstash|elasticsearch - Maintaining Original Insertion Sequence

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This can be solved as either a `logstash` or `elasticsearch` problem.

`logstash` is populating my `elasticsearch` index with records based on my log entries. A typical log entry looks a little like:

```
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] Message abc defg hijkl mnopq rstu vwxyz
```

This is being parsed-out by `logstash` into a document with the fields `@timestamp` `level` and `message`.

To attempt to re-assemble the logs in the correct order, one **could** sort the records by `@timestamp`. However, it is certainly possible to have two entries logged in the same millisecond, if not more.

Therefore, the results I get back from `elasticsearch` do not resemble the input. This is particularly evident when I'm logging a table:

```
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] +----+----+----+ 
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] | A  | B  | C  |
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] +----+----+----+
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] | 11 | 12 | 13 |
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] +----+----+----+
```

Is being returned in an arbitrary order, ending up with something like:

```
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] | 11 | 12 | 13 |
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] +----+----+----+
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] +----+----+----+
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] +----+----+----+
2001-01-01 01:01:01.001 [INFO] | A  | B  | C  |
```

Which is making the results from the `elasticsearch` queries un-usable.

Therefore, I need some mechanism that will either:

1. Have `logstash` record some original sequence-based information on the record that it inserts
2. Request `elasticsearch` to sort the results by the order in which they were inserted into the index.

I can't find any functionality in either tools for this, and I can see how this is going against the grain with some of their philosophical ideas. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create your own filter and have it inject a sequence number into all of your events and then you can use that as your secondary sort field behind timestamp.

It should be as simple as copying the `noop.rb` and adding a bit of code to define the sequence number variable and then set each event with `event["seq"] = seq++`

Comment: This will only work if you don't use it in a distributed system with multiple nodes and multiple logstash agents (or workers). In a distributed system, the 'original order' of things is pretty much undefined. Also Elasticsearch has shards and there is no notion of order between shards. So yes, unless you add something to sort on, there's not going to be a way to figure this out for elasticsearch. The filter idea probably works well.